# I have written callout get method for integration of facebook with salesforce. Can anyone tell how to write the test classes for this code

Tags: integration

**wrapper class:**

```java
public class facebookwrapper {
    public  string name         {set;get;}
    public  string firstname    {set;get;}
    public  string lastname     {set;get;}
}
```

**Apex class:**

```java
public class FbClass {
    public string appid                {set;get;}
    public string appsecret             {set;get;}
    public string redirecturl           {set;get;}
    public string code                  {set;get;}
    public string jsonString            {set;get;}
    public string accessToken           {set;get;}
    PUBLIC STRING   history             {set;get;}
    public string selfdetails           {set;get;}
    public list<facebookwrapper> fbwrap {set;get;}

    public FbClass(){
        appid = '922161527964144';
        appsecret = '<it"s a secret to everyone>';
        redirecturl = 'https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/FbClass';
        fbwrap=new list<facebookwrapper> ();
    }

    public PageReference fbaction(){
        HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
        string endpoint='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?';
        endpoint = endpoint+'client_id='+appid;
        endpoint = endpoint+'&redirect_uri='+redirecturl;
        endpoint = endpoint+'&scope=user_friends,ads_read,pages_manage_cta,user_videos';

        endpoint = endpoint+'&response_type=code';
        endpoint = endpoint+'&state=Venkat';
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        http h = new Http();
        res = h.send(req);
     // readCode();
        PageReference p=new PageReference(endpoint);
        return p;
    }

    public void code1(){
        code = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('code');
    }

    public void requestToken(){
        String url ='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?';
        url = url+'client_id='+appid;
        url = url+'&redirect_uri='+redirecturl;
        url = url+'&client_secret='+appsecret;
        url = url+'&code='+code;
        Http p = new Http();
        HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setEndPoint(url);
        HttpResponse response = p.send(request);
        // once your getting the response for yor request
        jsonString = response.getBody();
        System.JSONParser js = JSON.createParser(jsonString);
        system.debug('In Access Token method'+jsonString);
        while(js.nextToken() != null){
            if(js.getText() == 'access_token'){
                js.nextToken();
                accessToken = js.getText();
            }
        }
    }

    public void gethistory(){
        HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        //string idd = 'AaJ31OBeGO-0suOHezvMaf_p_RdgIN4lIg4x3es3DSXplEIisSaEXzpGZnpuuy-GtqSfCN6fnjmXx1iPVs5bIaBE-qvYZNCxghWaJdYvSOovrQ';
        // req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/work-experience-idd HTTP/1.1');
        // req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/2034133706611611/statuses');
        //req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/friend-list-id');
        req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=work,education');
        req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accessToken);
        HttpResponse res = null;
        http h = new Http();
        res = h.send(req);
        history=res.getbody();
        system.debug( 'hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii'+res.getbody());
        //  System.JSONParser jp=JSON.createParser(history);
    }

    public void datagetting(){
        HttpRequest req  =new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        string url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=taggable_friends{name,first_name,last_name}';
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accessToken);
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http h = new Http();
        res = h.send(req);
        system.debug( 'hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii'+res.getbody());
        selfdetails = res.getbody();
        System.JSONParser js = JSON.createParser(selfdetails);
        while(js.nextToken() != null){
            string name1;
            string firstname;
            string lastname;
            if(js.getText() == 'name'){
                facebookwrapper fb=new facebookwrapper();
                js.nextToken();
                name1 = js.getText();
                system.debug('Namessss'+name1);
                fb.name = name1;
                system.debug('Nameeee:'+fb);
                js.nextToken();
                if(js.getText() == 'first_name'){
                js.nextToken();
                firstname = js.getText();
                system.debug('Firstnamessssssss:'+firstname);
                fb.firstname = firstname;
                system.debug('Firstnames11111111111111111111:'+fb);
                system.debug('FaceBookWrapper:'+fbwrap);
                js.nextToken();
                if(js.getText() == 'last_name'){
                    js.nextToken();
                    lastname = js.getText();
                    fb.lastname = lastname;
                    fbwrap.add(fb);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}


}
```

**VF page:**

```html
<apex:page controller="FbClass">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!fbaction}" value="click" />

            <apex:commandButton action="{!code1}" value="code" />
            {!code}
            <apex:commandButton action="{!requestToken}" value="Token" />
            {!accessToken}
            <apex:commandButton action="{!gethistory}" value="history" />
            {!history}
            <apex:commandButton action="{!datagetting}" value="Data" />
            {!selfdetails}

        </apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!fbwrap}" var="x">
                <apex:column value="{!x.name}" headerValue="Names" />
                <apex:column headerValue="FirstName" value="{!x.firstname}"/>   
                <apex:column headerValue="Lastnames" value="{!x.lastname}" />
            </apex:pageblocktable>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The point of an api secret is that you're not supposed to let anyone else know what that value is. I've removed that from your question (though people can still see it if they know where to look), but it would still be a good idea to have Facebook give you a new app secret.

Comment: Also, your code formatting was all over the place. I've fixed that for you this time but, in the future, I'd like to see more effort on your part next time. Consistent code formatting helps others to understand your code. If you're serious about asking for help, then removing all the barriers to answering your question that you can is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this over [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206303/how-to-write-a-test-class-for-the-remoteaction-with-httpsrequest/206304#206304) as well please check how to test the callouts in Apex

Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the `HttpCalloutMock Interface`

```
global class ***YourHttpCalloutMockImpl*** implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Create a fake response.
        // Set response values, and 
        // return response.
    }
}
```

Now as we have set the fake response we need to send this fake response by calling `Test.setMock` in test method

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new YourHttpCalloutMockImpl());
```

Below is the sample mock test class

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        System.assertEquals('http://example.com/example/test', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"example":"test"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Below is the sample test class

```
@isTest
private class CalloutClassTest {
     @isTest static void testCallout() {
        // Set mock callout class 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());

        // Call method to test.
        // This causes a fake response to be sent
        // from the class that implements HttpCalloutMock. 
        HttpResponse res = CalloutClass.getInfoFromExternalService();

        // Verify response received contains fake values
        String contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String actualValue = res.getBody();
        String expectedValue = '{"example":"test"}';
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
    }
}

public class CalloutClass {
    public static HttpResponse getInfoFromExternalService() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://example.com/example/test');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        return res;
    }
}
```

For more detail please see the [standard doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm)

Comment: Hi RCS,  HttpResponse res = CalloutClass.getInfoFromExternalService(); in this response, what is CalloutClass? From where you took that class.

Comment: Hi RCS, i got u about CalloutClass.

Comment: what is this end point URL : http://example.com/example/test

Comment: @VenkatNarayan Yup its the endpoint URL and CalloutClass is the class from where we make the actual callout. Please mark the answer as done if u're clear.

Comment: if we have to write this code in separate class or in the same class as u have written                                                                                                                                                         public class CalloutClass {
    public static HttpResponse getInfoFromExternalService() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://example.com/example/test');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        return res;
    }
}

Comment: in the endpoint url i have to mention my VF page or apex class page?